# Telerik RadGrid with Button Column and Databind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a table with certain rows and columns. I need to use Dataset to Databind the Telerik RadGrid. Along with this, I need to display extra button column at the end. How can I achieve that? Could you please provide me simple example with Telerik tags in aspx and Databind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use it in my app. You need to add MasterTableView in Your RadGrid and define your buttons.

```
<MasterTableView
                AllowPaging="true"
                PageSize="15"
                DataKeyNames="ID"
                EditMode="PopUp"

                CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                AllowFilteringByColumn="false">


                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton">
                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" Display="false"/>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOKUMENT_DANEID" HeaderText="DOKUMENT_DANEID" Display="false"/>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOKUMENT_TYPEID" HeaderText="DOKUMENT_DANEID" Display="false"/>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NAME" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Resource, grid_dok_name %>"/>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TYPe" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Resource, grid_dok_type %>"/>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DESC" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Resource, grid_dok_desc %>"/>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PATH" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Resource, grid_dok_plik %>"/>
                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn DataTextFormatString="Select {0}"
                                              ButtonType="ImageButton" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Resource, grid_dok_atta %>"
                                              ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                              DataTextField="Open" CommandName="Select" ImageUrl="~\images\App\download.png">
                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete">
                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                </Columns>
                <EditFormSettings UserControlName="../forms/dok_item.ascx" PopUpSettings-Width="380px" EditFormType="WebUserControl">
                    <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1">
                    </EditColumn>
                </EditFormSettings>


            </MasterTableView>
```

Comment: Also, review the use of the NeedDataSource event in case you will be providing your own data structure as data source: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/simple-vs-advanced/defaultcs.aspx and maybe look into manual CRUD operations if you will not be using a declarative data source: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/manual-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: I am getting details from the database using stored procedure with certain records like ID, First Name, Last Name. I need to add a custom button column called Reject at the end of all the columns and this Reject button should be assiciated with the ID of each row. On click of Reject button, I need to process the data and update the database accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow telerik docs [Buttom Column](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#button) there are many samples how to use telerik controls.

```
    <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
  ...
  <MasterTableView DataSourceID="ProductsDataSource" TableLayout="Auto">
    ...
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductID" DataType="System.Int32" HeaderText="Product ID"
        SortExpression="ProductID" UniqueName="ProductID">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" SortExpression="ProductName"
        UniqueName="ProductName">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UnitPrice" DataType="System.Decimal" HeaderText="Unit Price"
        SortExpression="UnitPrice" UniqueName="UnitPrice">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
    ...
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```